# Matmul input and weight matrices order?

Tags: machine-learning, matrix-multiplication

I saw many ML tutorials explained fully connected network by constructing two matrices, weight matrix and input(or activation) matrix and perform a matrix to matrix multiplication (matmul) to form the linear equations.

All the examples I saw place input as first argument to matmul and weight tensor as second argument. Why is that? Why can’t I perform weights times input (assuming the weight matrix was created properly with columns count equal to input matrix row counts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get (nx1) output For a (nx1) input, you should multiplicate input with a (nxn) matrix  from left or (1x1) matrix from right.

If you multiplicate input with a scalar ( (1x1) matrix), then there are one connection from input to output from each neuron. If you multiplicate it with a matrix, for each output cell we get weighted sum of input neurons. In other words, each neuron in input connected to  each neuron in output which is **fully connected**.

[image]

By preserving this logic, it doesn't matter how you arrange your weight matrices.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I’m puzzling with the 1xn weights idea. If we have input [n, 1] * weight [1,n] isn’t the output becomes [n,n] so not [n,1] anymore?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with dimensions, now it's edited.

Comment: Thank you Kerem! My interpretation is that depending on how we choose the weight tensor if it’s a vector, then it’s a 1:1 relationship between input and output. If the weight is a matrix, then it’s fully connected because each output neuron receives a weighted sum from all input neurons.

Comment: Then, within fully connected or 1:1 operations we can choose to place input either on the left hand side or right hand side and transpose the weight matrix/vector accordingly

Comment: Yes, this is the exact interpretation.